# Trying to change image when JButton pressed

Tags: java, image, jpanel, jbutton, imageicon

I am trying to change the Image on the panel when the any of the JButtons are pressed. I have set up an array of images and need it to change to the next image in the array once it has been pressed. Here is my code:

```
public class SimpleGui implements ActionListener {
    JButton button = new JButton("Very Happy");
    JButton buttonTwo = new JButton("Happy");
    JButton buttonThree = new JButton("Neutral");
    JButton buttonFour = new JButton("Sad");
    JButton buttonFive = new JButton("Very Sad");
    static int[] ButtonArray = new int[5];
    private static String[] imageList = { "res/snow.jpg", "res/test-gm.jpg" };

    public int i = 0;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {

        SimpleGui gui = new SimpleGui();
        gui.go();

        File file = new File("out.txt");
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
        PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(fos);
        System.setOut(ps);

        ButtonArray[0] = 0;
        ButtonArray[1] = 0;
        ButtonArray[2] = 0;
        ButtonArray[3] = 0;
        ButtonArray[4] = 0;

    }

    public void go() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setBackground(Color.darkGray);

        panel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(panel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));

        button.addActionListener(this);
        buttonTwo.addActionListener(this);
        buttonThree.addActionListener(this);
        buttonFour.addActionListener(this);
        buttonFive.addActionListener(this);
        panel.add(button);
        panel.add(buttonTwo);
        panel.add(buttonThree);
        panel.add(buttonFour);
        panel.add(buttonFive);

        frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.EAST, panel);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(650, 600);
        frame.setVisible(true);

        ImageIcon image = new ImageIcon(imageList[i]);
        ImageIcon image1 = new ImageIcon(imageList[i + 1]);
        JLabel label = new JLabel("", image, JLabel.CENTER);
        JPanel panel2 = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        panel2.add(label, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        panel2.setLayout(new BoxLayout(panel2, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
        frame.add(panel2, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {

        if (event.getSource() == button) {
            ButtonArray[0] = 1;
            ButtonArray[1] = 0;
            ButtonArray[2] = 0;
            ButtonArray[3] = 0;
            ButtonArray[4] = 0;
            System.out.println("Very Happy");

        }
        // buttonTwo = (JButton) event.getSource();
        if (event.getSource() == buttonTwo) {
            ButtonArray[0] = 0;
            ButtonArray[1] = 1;
            ButtonArray[2] = 0;
            ButtonArray[3] = 0;
            ButtonArray[4] = 0;
            System.out.println("Happy");

        }
        // buttonThree = (JButton) event.getSource();
        if (event.getSource() == buttonThree) {
            ButtonArray[0] = 0;
            ButtonArray[1] = 0;
            ButtonArray[2] = 1;
            ButtonArray[3] = 0;
            ButtonArray[4] = 0;
            System.out.println("Neutral");

        }
        // buttonFour = (JButton) event.getSource();
        if (event.getSource() == buttonFour) {
            ButtonArray[0] = 0;
            ButtonArray[1] = 0;
            ButtonArray[2] = 0;
            ButtonArray[3] = 1;
            ButtonArray[4] = 0;
            System.out.println("Sad");

        }

        // buttonFive = (JButton) event.getSource();
        if (event.getSource() == buttonFive) {
            ButtonArray[0] = 0;
            ButtonArray[1] = 0;
            ButtonArray[2] = 0;
            ButtonArray[3] = 0;
            ButtonArray[4] = 1;
            System.out.println("Very Sad");

        }

        // System.out.println(Arrays.toString(ButtonArray));
        // ImageIcon image = (imageList[i]);

    }

}
```

Comment: Sorry, it is my first time using this website. I originally had i = i+1; at the end of each if statement hoping that it would then choose the image[1] for the ImageIcon as in the line ImageIcon image = new ImageIcon(imageList[i]); however it doesn't change image when I run it

Comment: Well, you never change the image in the button... also, what's the purpose of that `ButtonArray` array?

Comment: There is no purpose to this, it was a method I was using earlier to save the user input but I've removed it now, sorry about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't really see what most parts of you code are supposed to do. So instead, here's a minimal example that should do what you are asking about: One label, and two buttons setting different images to that label.

```
ImageIcon[] images = new ImageIcon[] {
        new ImageIcon("foo.gif"),
        new ImageIcon("bar.gif"),
        new ImageIcon("blub.gif")
};

JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test");
frame.getContentPane().setLayout(new FlowLayout());

JLabel label = new JLabel(images[0]);
frame.getContentPane().add(label);

JButton button1 = new JButton("Image 1");
button1.addActionListener(e -> label.setIcon(images[0]));
frame.getContentPane().add(button1);

JButton button2 = new JButton("Image 2");
button2.addActionListener(e -> label.setIcon(images[1]));
frame.getContentPane().add(button2);

frame.pack();
frame.setVisible(true);
```

Note that this is using Lambda functions (Java 8) but you can do the same with one or more "real" `ActionListener` classes. The important part is that you call `label.setIcon(theImage)`; this part seems to be missing in your code.

---

If instead you want to cycle through a list or array of pictures, you can do like this:

```
AtomicInteger index = new AtomicInteger(0);
JButton buttonCycle = new JButton("Cycle");
buttonCycle.addActionListener(e -> label.setIcon(images[index.getAndIncrement() % images.length]));
frame.getContentPane().add(buttonCycle);
```

Here, the `AtomicInteger` is used so I can declare it as a local variable and use it in the lambda. You can just as well use a regular `int` if you make it a member variable of the surrounding class.

```
private int c = 0;
...
buttonCycle.addActionListener(e -> label.setIcon(images[c++ % images.length]));
```

The takeaway is: Create a counter variable, increment it each time the button is called and set the label's icon to the element with that count, module the size of the array.

Comment: Sorry I appeared to have asked the question in a confusing manner. Basically I don't want to set each button to a particular picture, I want to do it that whenever one of the JButtons which have already been declared is pressed the image changes to whatever image is next in the array. Right now there are only 2 images in the array, there will actually be 100.

Comment: Thank you very much Tobias! I really appreciate it.